# Can someone explain to me what the code below is doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails tutorial and I have no idea what

```
@comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
```

is doing in the code:

```
 def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article_id = params[:arcticle_id]
    @comment.save
    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
 end
```

Also, does the `params[:article_id]` get transferred into the instance variable on the left ?

Comment: it assign `article_id` to `comment object` before save.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this code should be probably written as `@comment = Comment.create!(comment.params.merge(article_id: params[:arcticle_id])`.

Comment: Is `params[:arcticle_id]` a typo?  I'd expect it to be `params[:article_id]`.  If the form (or whatever) is actually sending through `arcticle_id` then you should fix the form as this will just cause confusion.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thanks! fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about Rails **"Active Record Associations"**

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comments < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

When you create `has_many` and `belongs_to` relation between two tables you need to store `article.id` in comments table then comments related to that particular article.

In your code:

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.article_id = params[:arcticle_id]

    @comment.save

    redirect_to article_path(@comment.article)
end
```

You are creating comment for an article so when you do

> @comment.article_id = params[:arcticle_id]

it will store the article.id in this comment so this comment related to that particular article.

Read [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Another thing I dont get is where the params[:article_id] gets substituted into. Does it go into @comment or @comment.article_id? I would like to know the order(I know code is read from right to left when it is a variable).

Comment: Actually `comments` table has `article_id` attribute same like `foreign key`  so `article_id` will store in comment.article_id.

Comment: When you do `@article.comments` it will show all the comments which have `@article.id` stored in there `article_id` column ( comment.article_id)

Answer (score 0):

since you are using a relational database the 'artical_id' is used to create a relation between the comment and the article that it belongs to.

So the code:

```
@comment.artical_id = params[:artical_id]
```

is used to give the comment it's article id so it can be referred back to later.

Hope this help